# How to get Many enum sources in the same ListBox

Tags: c#, enums, listbox

I have these enums that i am trying to get into the same ListBox.

```
public enum Mammals
{
    BlueWhale,
    Monkey
}

public enum Reptiles
{
    Lizzard,
    Python
}

List <object> allAnimals =new List<object>();

animals_lbx.DataSource = allAnimals;
```

To get one of the lists into the listbox i could simply write:

```
     animals_lbx.DataSource( Enum.GetValues(typeof(Mammals));
```

but how do i get the both Enum-sources in the same ListBox?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use

[ListBox.Items.AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.addrange?view=netframework-4.8)

> Adds a group of items to the list of items for a ListBox.

```
animals_lbx.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Mammals));
animals_lbx.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Reptiles));
```

**Update**

oops, you will need to cast it, as [`Enum.GetValues`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=netframework-4.8) returns an `System.Array` and `AddRange` expects an `object[]`

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Mammals)).Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Comment: i get the errormessage: Cannot convert from System.Array to System.Windows.Forms.Listbox.ObjectCollection